# VBA Excel Script to copy rows with data from one worksheet & paste into another with out overwritting

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Excel 2007

I'm trying to run a VBA script that will copy a list of sales Ledgers from one worksheet titled MSL with the columns DATE, INVOICE NO, COMPANY NAME, TOTAL, SUB-TOTAL, NETT, VAT.

1st problem i'm having is i only want to copy rows 2 and onward which contain a record and this number will change each month depending on sales.

e.g. Jan has 30 rows
     Feb has 24 rows
     Mar has 40 rows

Next i need to paste the data in to a new worksheet titled "SalesDB" with the same columns DATE, INVOICE NO, COMPANY NAME, TOTAL, SUB-TOTAL, NETT, VAT.

Next problem im having is the data is overwriting.

Thanks for any help
*will be out for the next hour collecting kids from school*

Comment: To clarify, each month you want to copy the latest sales data for that month in worksheet MSL to worksheet SalesDB but retain all prior months data in SalesDB i.e. SalesDB retains sales history from prior months?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Worksheet MLS` is like the following and `Worksheet SalesDB` is same format:

```
    A      B           C               D       E           F       G 
1   Date   Invoice No  Company Name    Total   Sub-Total   Nett    VAT  
2
```

This code will grab data from `MLS` taking account of number of entries and add to `SalesDB` and avoid overwriting.

```
 Sub CopyPasteSales
     Dim salesData as range, targetRng as range

     Set salesData = Worksheets("MLS").Range("A2:G" & Range("A1").end(xlDown).Row)

     If Worksheets("SalesDB").Range("A2") = vbNullString Then
          Set targetRng = Worksheets("SalesDB").Range("A2") //If no data in SalesDB start in row 2
     Else
          Set targetRng = Worksheets("SalesDB").Range("A1").end(xlDown).Offset(1,0) //If data already in SalesDB, find next free row
     End if

     salesData.Copy Destination:= targetRng
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help im really grateful seems to be doing everything i required though can't properly test till my little boys down

Comment: Getting an error "cant execute code in break mode" at the set targetRng line which is strange as it did work? Had to change MLS to MSL

Comment: Edit, Sorry the error is

Run-time error '1004'

Application-defined or object defined error

@Remnant

Comment: If you don't have any data in SalesDB it will give error. I ahev now updated code to handle case where you don't already have data in SalesDB

Answer (score 0):

Short and dynamic: (not tested, may contain typos)

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim src As Range, dest As Range
    'set source, exclude first row
    Set src = Worksheets("MLS").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    'destination is one row below last row
    Set dest = Worksheets("SalesDB").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    src.Copy Destination:=dest
End Sub
```